# Why is $\partial\partial M=\varnothing$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, manifolds, differential-topology

Why is the border of the border of an oriented differentiable $n$-dimensional Manifold $M$ empty, that is $$\partial\partial M = \emptyset?$$

Comment: Well, what is the boundary of the boundary of a closed half-space in $\mathbb R^n$? Since manifolds are locally like closed half-spaces of $\mathbb R^n$ and the boundary is computed locally, this gives you the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simply says that the boundary of the manifold $M$ is a manifold without boundary. Indeed, by definition, it is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ by restriction of the atlas of $M$ to $\partial M$. Note this has nothing to do with the differential structure.

**Note:** I think it is worth noting that the boundary $\partial^\mathrm{man}$ of a manifold is a notion which is different from that of [boundary in a general topological space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29) $\partial^\mathrm{top}$. For instance, $\partial^\mathrm{man}(0,1)=\emptyset$ while $\partial^\mathrm{top}(0,1)=\{0,1\}$. To avoid confusion, some people call $\partial^\mathrm{top}$ the fronteer.

It is not true that $\partial^\mathrm{top}\partial^\mathrm{top} S=\emptyset$ in general. Precisely, in the case of a closed half-space, $\partial^\mathrm{top}\partial^\mathrm{top} S=\partial ^\mathrm{top}S\neq \emptyset$. For instance, 
$$
\partial^\mathrm{top} \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;;\;y\geq 0\}=\partial^\mathrm{man} \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;;\;y\geq 0\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\;;\;y=0\}=B
$$
and
$$
\partial^\mathrm{top}B=B\qquad\text{while}\qquad \partial^\mathrm{man}B=\emptyset
$$
as $B$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot to whoever took the time to do the $\rm$ edit.

Comment: Can you help me with this please ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361342/mass-of-a-rectangle/361368?noredirect=1#comment776388_361368

Answer (score 5):

Let M be a manifold and $\omega>0$ be a function. By twice use of Stokes Theorem:

$$\int_M d^2 \omega=\int_M d(d(\omega))=\int_{\partial M}d\omega=\int_{\partial{\partial M}} \omega $$

Since $d^2 \omega=0$ always (property of exterior derivative) then $\int_{\partial{\partial M}} \omega=0$ and because $\omega>0$ then $\partial\partial M=0$.

Comment: You can only integrate top-dimensional forms on a manifold. So if $\dim(M) = n$, $\omega$ needs to be a $(n - 2)$-form, not a function.