# Mass of a rectangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $c<a$. Suppose given is a thin plate $R$ in the plane bounded by $$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}=1, \frac{x}{c}+\frac{y}{b}=1, y=0$$ and such that the density of a point $(x,y) \in R$ is given by $\delta(x,y)=x$. Compute the mass of $R$

I know that by definition $m(R)= \iint_R f(x,y)dxdy$ and the definition of the density is mass/area ie $\delta(x,y)=\frac{\iint_R f(x,y)dxdy}{\iint_Rdxdy}$

But I am not sure how to proceed. First of all what is $f(x,y)$? Is it equal to $1$?
Second of all, how do I determine the limits of the integrals ?

Thank you

Comment: Your interpretation of $m(R)$ is wrong. See Coffee_Table's answer. The main bulk of this problem is to parametrize the domain to apply Fubini.

Comment: @julien Can you write for me a complete answer? Because I have 5 other problems to do in the same style. (I am practicing for an exam(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two dimensions we have that
$$\text{Mass}=\iint_R \delta(x,y)dxdy$$
In other words, mass is simply the integral of the density function over the region in question. Intuitively, we are continuously summing the mass distribution (i.e., the density) over the region in question, which gives the mass.

So now all you need is to find the limits of integration based on the boundary of the plate $R$. Notice the equations can be rewritten as $$y=0,$$ $$y=-\frac{b}{a}x+b,$$ $$y=-\frac{b}{c}x+b.$$
This describes a simple triangular region enclosed by these three equations. Since $c<a$ the third equation is the "lower" line. For a very helpful picture of what is going on, see an example [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427em6vj01e3t0) where I set $a=5,b=3,c=4$ (you can clearly see the region that is bounded in that example, its in the first quadrant by the way). Now we can set the limits of integration by observing that for each $y$ on the interval $[0,b]$, $x$ varies between (solving from the previous equations)
 $$x=-\frac{c}{b}y+c,$$ and $$x=-\frac{a}{b}y+a.$$ Finally we can write the integral as  $$\text{Mass}=\iint_R \delta(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^b \int_{-\frac{c}{b}y+c}^{-\frac{a}{b}y+a} xdxdy.$$
You should now be able to evaluate the integral.

Comment: @Coffe_Table No I'm trying to calculate the "mass" as stated above

Comment: @user43418 perhaps my edited post is more helpful.

Comment: Ok. I will try finding them myself and then I will post it for you. Could you explain a bit more why to we have the above relation ? Thanks

Comment: I am a little confused. In the question, they tell us that y=0, does that mean that the region to consider is such that $c \leq x \leq a$ ?

Comment: @user43418 : 1) where does $a$ come into the picture? it is not mentioned in any of your equations! 2) Also, by $y=0$ they mean the x-axis, i.e., the line $y=0$, where the y coordinate has no elevation. (Also, I edited my answer to give a brief intuition on why this relation holds).

Comment: Can you write for me a complete answer? Because I have 5 other problems to do in the same style. (I am practicing for an exam(

Comment: @user43418 : before I do so, can you clarify where the $a$ comes in? it is not in the equations given...perhaps you meant $x/a$ in the first equation?

Comment: What will be the form of the moments of inertia along the x-axsis and y-axsis?

Comment: @user43418 I'm not really so sure about that, forgot some of my physics! Sorry. Check out Wikipedia and perhaps ask this as a separate question on this site.

Comment: Here is the post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361494/determining-the-moment-of-inertia

Comment: @user43418 : see my answer to the other question. the integration stays the same.