# $H_1, H_2$ groups. $|H_1 |= n_1, |H_2| = n_2$. Prove $|H_1 \times H_2| = n$ where $n = \mathrm{lcm}(n_1,n_2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

> Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be groups. Prove that if $a_1 \in H_1$ has order $n_1$ and $a_2 \in H_2$ has order $n_2$, then the order of $(a_1, a_2)$ in $H_1 \times H_2$ is $n$, where $n = \mathrm{lcm}(n_1, n_2)$. Hence, or otherwise, find all possible orders of elements of $G_{56}$. You are not requred to find elements of these orders.

For the proof, what I have said is if $n_1 = |H_1|$ and $n_2 = |H_2|$ and $a_1 \in H_1$ and $a_2 \in H_2$ then

$$a_1^{n_1} = 1 \hspace{1.5cm} a_2^{n_2} = 1.$$

If $n = \mathrm{lcm}(n_1, n_2) \implies n_1 \mid n \, \, \mathrm{and} \, \, n_2 \mid n$ and so we get

$$a_1^n = 1 \hspace{1.5cm} a_2^n = 1.$$

So if $(a_1, a_2) \in H_1 \times H_2$ then

$$(a_1, a_2)^n = (a_1^n, a_2^n) = (1,1)$$

proving what I needed to prove. Is this correct?

For the second bit, I have said that

$$G_{56} \cong G_8 \times G_7$$

but I'm a little confused as to if the elements then have order $2$ (as $8 = 2^3$) and $7$ or $8$ and $7$. Which way round is it?

Comment: 56 is not $6\times 7$

Comment: @Lost1 Sorry, typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title doesn't match your question. In fact, $H_1,H_2$ needn't even be finite groups in order to conclude that $(a_1,a_2)$ has order $n=\text{lcm}(n_1,n_2).$ What you've shown is that the order of $(a_1,a_2)$ is at most $n$. You still have to show that if $0<k<n$, then $(a_1,a_2)^k\neq(1,1).$ Recall that since the orders of $a_1,a_2$ are respectively $n_1,n_2$, then $a_1^{n_1}\ne1$ for $0<j<n_1$ and $a_2^{n_2}\ne1$ for $0<j<n_2$.

As for your second part, what is $G_{56}$? Regardless, the possible orders of elements of a group of order $56$ are the positive divisors of $56.$

Comment: "$G_n$ is called the group of units $\mod n$". I don't really understand what that means though. Is that simply for any $a \in G_n$, we can write it as $a \equiv \pm 1 \mod n$?

Comment: Also, because I split $56 = 2^3 \times 7$, I can just take different combinations of this that give me 56 and that's the order right? Like I can say $2 \times (2^2 cdot 7)$, etc?

Comment: @CameronBuie Can you help me with this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361342/mass-of-a-rectangle/361368?noredirect=1#comment776518_361368

I am trying to find the moments of inertia in this case

Comment: The units mod $n$ are the elements of $\Bbb Z_n$ that are coprime to $n$. The order of $G_n$ is $\phi(n),$ where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function. $G_{55}$ has order $24$, so the possible orders of elements will be the divisors of $24$.